# Meteor prevent methods from being called from console

Tags: meteor, methods, console

I have a Meteor game of heads or tails that keeps the stats of a user in their profile. The stats eg. wins and loses are changed using Meteor methods like incrementWins and incrementLoses.

Is there a way to prevent the users from calling these methods on the console?

Comment: Not really, and you should not count on any hackery that makes it appear like there is. Users have control over their platform, and you should not trust any value coming from the client. The server should be in charge of changing the users stats, not the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find any precise answer to the question so I'll add one.

> Is there a way to prevent the users from calling these methods on the console?

The short answer is **no**.

As long as you have the `Meteor` variable available on the client, it's not possible to restrict a user to use if from browser console. Meteor allows the client side to use `Meteor.call` function in any conditions, therefore even if you restrict its usage somehow, it will affect your whole application, not just browser console.

You can, however, make your methods more secure. As you know, you can make your code run either on client side, server side, or both. If you put your methods on the server side, the client side will never know *what exactly* happens as the methods are executed, nor would it be able to influence it or intercept control anyhow.

On the other hand, if you put your methods in the lib/ or both/ folder (or simply root folder of your app), the methods will run both on client and on server. Insecure part of the code (like bulk removing collection items or manipulating `Meteor.users` collection) won't be executed on the client side. But you may want to put something that would change UI state or show any messages, ironically, on the browser console. Think twice before applying this practice.

I personally think you exaggerate the meaning of ability to run something on the browser console. First, only a small group of users actually do that (but if they do, expect smallest holes in your app to be exploited). Second, Meteor is well secured in this part, it doesn't allow a user to run insecure code (unless `insecure` package is added, which is by default as you create a new app). And third, most of the time, as your methods get executed, the data will be updated reactively, this is what Meteor takes care of out of the box, so you don't need to worry about refreshing UI after app state change, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed description, I've figured out a solution to my problem based off of this information :)

Answer (score 0):

Every newly created Meteor project has the insecure package added by default. This is the package that allows us to edit the database from the client. It's useful when prototyping, To remove this package, go to your app directory and run:

```
meteor remove insecure
```